# How can I expose a callback from my Bazel cc_library so it can be called from libSDL2 in my Android project?

Tags: android, sdl-2, bazel

The SDL2 Android project includes an Android Activity class (SDLActivity) that passes the name of a C library and callback within it to SDL_android.c using a JNI call to `nativeRunMain()`. The C callback is then invoked dynamically using `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

However, when running `adb logcat`, nativeRunMain() says that it `Couldn't find function main in library lib<android-binary>.so`.

My cc_library definition looks like this:

```
cc_library(
  name = "main",
  srcs = ["jni/main.c"],
  deps = [
    "@libSDL2//:lib"
  ]
)
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...
}
```

Reproduciable example code here:
https://files.fm/u/hr62nbr3

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example project? It'll be helpful to see the full BUILD and source files and project structure.

Comment: There you go.
https://files.fm/u/hr62nbr3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` isn't exported as a symbol because it is reserved function name, changing the name to something else fixes this issue.

Using `nm -D` to inspect the dynamic symbol table of the .so file, I can see `main` isn't being exported as a symbol. Changing the name of the function `main` to something else means it will be available.